# xterm settings in Manjaro Xfce

Tags: xterm, manjaro

I'd like to edit the default settings of xterm in Manjaro through the ctrl-mouse click option, but whenever I try that, the xterm window just disappears. Am I doing something wrong? Using the latest Manjaro, installed on 2018/03/28.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install **xorg-fonts-misc** and see if it fixes.

One of the few archived bug reports about this issue [dates back to 2004](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=222530).